# Cannot write to file with specified path in Python

Tags: python, file-io, path

I am working on a script to get my present workind directory, concatenate it to "cd" and write that string to a file. However whenever I try to specify the path I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home/cameron/projects/personal/new_window/last_directory.txt'
```

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# Get working directory and transform into command string
stream = os.popen('pwd')
output = "cd " + stream.readline()

path = 'home/cameron/projects/personal/new_window/last_directory.txt'

# Open and write command to file
file = open(path,'w')
file.write(output)
file.close()

# Print status
print("Current Directory written:")
print(stream)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'd like to write this command so that when I'm deep in a file tree I can save it's location in the case I need to open another window. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe start with `r'/home/cameron..'`

Comment: use ```os.getcwd()``` to find current working dir. comment what you get

Comment: Thank you guys! Sid your solution worked. I believe the "r" was a typo right?

Answer (score 0):

`path` likely needs to start with a `/` for your OS.

The directories in the path must also exist prior to writing. You can make them if they don't yet exist with:

```
if not os.path.exists(path):
     os.makedirs(path)
```